# JQuery UI sortable: как вызвать событие при помещении элемента с определенным классом?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sortable

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в jQuery ui sortable сделать вызов события при помещение в область сортировки элемента с **определенным** классом.

Например, есть список:

```
html:
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="sort1">1</li>
  <li class="sort1">2</li>
  <li class="sort1">3</li>
</ul>

JS:
var ul_sortable = $('.sortable');
ul_sortable.sortable({
    revert: 100,
    update: function() { 
                        //сработает при перемещении объектов
    }
});
ul_sortable.disableSelection();
```

Если я помещу в список  ещё один элемент, но с другим классом, например:"`<li class="sort2">4</li>`", то событие не должно срабатывать. Но, если я помещу элемент с классом `sort1`, то должно срабатывать событие

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ul_sortable.sortable({
  revert: 100,
  update: function(event, ui) { 
    if (ui.item.hasClass("sort1")) {
      // При перемещении элемента .sort1
    } else {
      // В остальных случаях
    }
  }
});
```